# Calculating mean and standard deviation using Spark / SCALA

Tags: scala, apache-spark

I have a dataframe :

```
+------------------+
|         speed    |
+------------------+
|               0.0|
|               0.0|
|               0.0|
|               0.0|
|               0.0|
|               0.0|
| 3.851015222867941|
| 4.456657435740331|
|               0.0|
|               NaN|
|               0.0|
|               0.0|
|               NaN|
|               0.0|
|               0.0|
| 5.424094717765175|
|1.5781185921913181|
|2.6695439462433033|
| 17.43513658955467|
| 5.440912941359523|
|11.507138536880484|
|12.895677610360089|
| 9.930875909722456|
+------------------+
```

I want to calculate the mean and the standard deviation of speed column .
**When I execute this code**

```
dataframe_final.select("speed").orderBy("id").agg(avg("speed")).show(1000)
```

**I get**

```
+------------+
|avg(speed)|
+------------+
|         NaN|
+------------+
```

**Where does the problem comes from ? any posibility to solve it ?**

**Thanks**

Comment: `agg(avg("Vitesse"))` will try to calculate the average the column `Vitesse` after a `groupBy`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You have `NaN` (Not a Number) values in your dataset. You cannot calculate an average with those.

Either you filter them:

```scala
dataframe_final
  .filter($"speed".isNotNull())
  .select("speed")
  .orderBy("id")
  .agg(avg("speed"))
  .show(1000)
```

Or replace them with a `0` using the [`fill` function](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/scala/index.html#org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrameNaFunctions):

```scala
dataframe_final
  .select("speed")
  .na.fill(0)
  .agg(avg("speed"))
  .show(1000)
```

Additionally you are trying to aggregate the `Vitesse` column and not the `speed`.

Comment: Thank you @nathan_gs . How can I replace 'Nan' values by 0 ?

Comment: Added this into the answer @HaJar

Answer (score 1):

```
we can also createOrReplaceTempView(dataframe_final) and then we can use spark sql to query and take avg of the speed column

val tableview= dataframe_final.createOrReplaceTempView()
val query = select avg(speed) from tableview where speed IS NOT NULL order by Id
spark.sql(query).show()
```